# Saving files to slow drive (sshfs)

Tags: notepad++, sshfs

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) blocks/freezes while saving to slow drive, so I'm waiting until it finishes.

Is there a way to tell notepad to perform saving in background and unblocks rest of the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Been using Windows for 20 years.  Notepad is your bare-bones text editor on the platform.  Not a lot of features.  Certainly not what you're looking for.

The problem with what you're asking for is that you'd never really know if the file finished saving.  Can you imagine working on a text file (or any other file) all day long and hitting save, and later turning off the computer.  Then you come back and discover that it never finished the save operation.

If you're having blocking issues against your network drive, you might consider doing a save to a local file FIRST, and then doing a copy.

Comment: yes, that would be general idea to postpone saving, but in more transparent fashion if possible.